# How to get a Json Object from an Array when getting data from Rapid API?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

When using axios for get data from a GET API from RapidAP, I get an array of JSON objects as seen in the pictures below. How can I use Typescript in React for just get the JSON objects'data within this array like my interface?

[the result from console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJW03.png)

```
import React, { Component, useState , useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const options: any = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://transfermarket.p.rapidapi.com/clubs/list-by-competition',
  params: {id: 'ES1'},
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'transfermarket.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'mykey'
  }
}

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});




interface clubObjects {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    image: string
}
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty simple. Replace `console.log(response.data);` with this code:

`const data = await response.json(); setResponse(data);`

`setResponse` is storing the object this state:

`const [response, setResponse] = useState<clubObjects[]>();`

Notice `<clubObjects[]>`, it sets the type of your state to an array of the clubObjects. Finally you can use `.map` function to display data of each object within the array.